# Increment column value when certain conditions are met in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that increments values for 2 columns based on the previous row, the caveat being that it should increment by 1 when a certain value is present and increment by 2 when another value is present.

I have shown the expected output in columns ID and NUMBER.

You can see 3 sets of data that repeat, this is highlighted by the ID column, this value should increment by 1 every 24 rows - 63, 64, 65 - this can be done manually but if there is a formula for this it that would be very useful.

The main part of this question is column NUMBER, when column C changes to 'emr_p_file' the NUMBER column should increment by 2 but when the next row changes to 'L2_*' then it should only increment by 1.

Row 1 values for ID and NUMBER can be static, from row 2 onwards they should be calculated by a formula of some sort.

Is something like this possible in excel, if so please help.

CSV export:
`link:`https://pastebin.com/zkjsB9L7

[image]

Comment: Use ROW and MOD to get the ID number to increment every 24 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting ID and NUMBER in cell `F1` and `G1` will be static, in cell `F2` enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=F1+(MOD(ROW(1:1),24)=0)
```

> the logic is to use **ROW** function to return the row number from previous row, and use **MOD** function to find out if it is fully divisible by `24`, if so increase the previous ID by 1 (which is `TRUE` returned by the equation in the brackets).

in cell `G2` enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=G1+IF(C2=C1,0,IF(FIND("_",C1)=3,2,1))
```

> the logic is to use nested **IF** functions to find out if the data set is the same as the previous data set, if so returns `0`, if not means there is a change of data set. The next IF will find out if the old data set starts by `LR` or `emr`, if former return `1` otherwise `2`.

I notice that your example starting **Row 49** is **NOT** increasing the values in `Column G: NUMBER` as prescribed. Can you please clarify if you provided incorrect expected outcome for those rows or if there is any missing criteria you did not mention in your post?

Comment: Thanks @Terry, that's perfect, both formulas did the job. Also yes you are right, row G was my mistake, I forgot to increment the values.